# Fitted planes' normal vector not perpendicular

Tags: data-visualization, python, matplotlib

I fitted a plane into a set of points in R3 using minimization of L2 error (taken from this post: https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6).

```
data = cluster_data[:ALLOWED_PEAKS, :]

grid_steps = 20

# regular grid covering the domain of the data
mn = np.min(data, axis=0)
mx = np.max(data, axis=0)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(mn[0], mx[0], grid_steps),
                   np.linspace(mn[1], mx[1], grid_steps))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()

# best-fit linear plane (1st-order)
A = np.c_[data[:, 0], data[:, 1], np.ones(data.shape[0])]
C, _, _, _ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:, 2])    # coefficients

# evaluate it on grid
Z = C[0] * X + C[1] * Y + C[2]

gci = int((grid_steps / 2) - 1 ) # grid_center_index

centroid = np.array([X[gci, gci], Y[gci, gci], Z[gci, gci]]).reshape(1,-1)  # take center point of grid steps

surface_norm = np.array([-C[0], -C[1], 1]).reshape(1,-1)

surface_norm_unit = normalize(surface_norm, norm='l2')

centroid_norm = centroid + surface_norm_unit
```

The plane looks like a great fit by visual inspection.

Now I want to find the normal vector of the plane. When looking at the code, the plane was determined by using an equation of the form

[image: cz = ax + by + d]

When assuming [image: c = 1], and using Wikipedia's knowledge about normal vectors on planes

> [For a plane given by the equation ax+by+cz+d=0, the vector (a,b,c) is a normal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry))

my normal vector should be `[ C[0], C[1], -1]` or `[ -C[0], -C[1], 1]`.

When plotting this normal vector, I receive a line that does not appear to be perpendicular on the plane.

[image]

Especially when looking from on side and making the plane appear to be a line (very thin, I hope you can see it)

[image]

Am I missing something fundamental about normal vectors? Is my assumption incorrect, that on the second image it should be orthogonal to the thin line?
Here is my code for plotting:

```
# plot points and fitted surface using Matplotlib
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2], c='r', s=50)
ax.quiver(*[*centroid.reshape(-1,).tolist(),*surface_norm_unit.reshape(-1,).tolist()])
ax.scatter(centroid[0,0], centroid[0,1], centroid[0,2], c='b', s=100)
ax.scatter(centroid_norm[0,0], centroid_norm[0,1], centroid_norm[0,2], c='b', s=100)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.axis('equal')
ax.axis('tight')
```

When multiplying the calculated normal vector with a vector on the plane, the result is `2.77555756e-17`, so nearly 0, which should be an indicator of both vectors being orthogonal.

Comment: Your plot is deceiving you because of the gross coordinate distortions.  You can evaluate angles visually *only* when all three coordinates are drawn on identical scales.  Try that and see whether the plane looks perpendicular to the normal vector.

Comment: @whuber , thank you very much, I feel like a fool. If I want to visualize I need the same scale. Just to be safe, I tested it with scaled axes on the graph an it works great. If you want to add it as a solution, I would mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue.

whuber is right about this.
I used `plt3d.autoscale(False)`,it worked for me. This answer is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3461869

For you this might work `ax = fig.gca(projection='3d',autoscale_on=False)`

ref: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes

If that did not work, find an appropriate method to turn off auto-scaling from matplotlib site.

It messed up my plot but I think it could be fixed by limiting the number of points to be drawn or by increasing the size of the canvas. I did not bother about fixing it.